# How to parse, or create pojo from following json array?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, jsonparser

I want to parse the following JSON and work fine using my code like string tokenizer, but I want to parse with any standard method (e.g. GSON.. etc), or how to create POJO for it, [using this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), so how to resolve this issue, Thanks

**JSON**

```
[
   [
      "106639",
      "jonni",
      "assistant director",
      "1"
   ],
   [
      "106639",
      "maikel",
      "operator and publisher",
      "1"
   ]
]
```

Comment: create pojo class related to incoming data and use Gson. You have an array of objects. Something like this human[] = new Gson().fromJson(<your json string>, Human[].class) check for details - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html

Comment: thanks but, tut link not like my JSON, I know how to handle JSON like key-pair value json but i does not know about above.

Comment: `Call<String>` probably should be `Call<ArrayList<SomeModel>>`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes but I am unable to create model, any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a custom json object. it is simple string array in array so you should use ArrayList> class type as below.

**Kotlin:**

```
val model = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()::class.java)
```

**Java:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> model = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>() {}.getType());
```

[TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

> `public class TypeToken<T> extends Object`
>
> Represents a generic type `T.Java` doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this
>   class does. Forces clients to create a subclass of this class which
>   enables retrieval the type information even at runtime. For example,
>   to create a type literal for `List<String>`, you can create an empty
>   anonymous inner class:
>
> `TypeToken<List<String>> list = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {};`
>
> This syntax cannot be used to create type literals that have wildcard
>   parameters, such as `Class<?> or List<? extends CharSequence>`.

Comment: working but show error with type parameter: “cannot select from parameterized type on ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>.class)

Comment: Yeah you are right. You need to use TypeToken to fix the error. I edited my answer.